# Regex for attribute value having quotes in between same as the enclosing quotes

Tags: php, regex

The string has multiple occurences of alt attr key-value. In the value of the alt attr is the string having double quotes (") present in it. This double quote is making the value terminate at the first occurrence of double quote instead of taking the full value. Please help to modify the regex to achieve the full alt value

```
$text = 'advcd<img loading="lazy" class="abcd pqr" alt="chi-phi-sinh-o-benh-v"ien-dai-hoc-y-duoc-co-so-2" attr="val"><img loading="lazy" class="abcd pqr" alt="abcd-sinh-o-benh-"ien-dai-hoc-y-duoc-co-so-3">sdfs';

preg_match_all('/(alt)=(["\'][^"\']*["\'])/i', $text, $matches);

if (count($matches) > 1) {
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Current Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => alt="chi-phi-sinh-o-benh-v\"
            [1] => alt="abcd-sinh-o-benh-\"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => alt
            [1] => alt
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => "chi-phi-sinh-o-benh-v\"
            [1] => "abcd-sinh-o-benh-\"
        )

)
```

Expected Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => alt="chi-phi-sinh-o-benh-v"ien-dai-hoc-y-duoc-co-so-2"
            [1] => alt="abcd-sinh-o-benh-"ien-dai-hoc-y-duoc-co-so-3"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => alt
            [1] => alt
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => "chi-phi-sinh-o-benh-v"ien-dai-hoc-y-duoc-co-so-2"
            [1] => "abcd-sinh-o-benh-"ien-dai-hoc-y-duoc-co-so-3"
        )

)
```

Comment: Use an XML parser instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the `"` in the attribute value to `&quot;` and then it is easier to use a dom parser to get the alt values:

```
$text = 'advcd<img loading="lazy" class="abcd pqr" alt="chi-phi-sinh-o-benh-v&quot;ien-dai-hoc-y-duoc-co-so-2" attr="val"><img loading="lazy" class="abcd pqr" alt="abcd-sinh-o-benh-&quot;ien-dai-hoc-y-duoc-co-so-3">sdfs';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($text, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

foreach($xpath->evaluate("//img/@alt") as $i) {
    echo $i->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;   
}
```

Output

```
chi-phi-sinh-o-benh-v"ien-dai-hoc-y-duoc-co-so-2
abcd-sinh-o-benh-"ien-dai-hoc-y-duoc-co-so-3
```

---

Using a regex for your examples strings:

- `(alt)=` Capture **group 1**, match alt followed by `=`
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `".*?"` match from `"` and then the least amount of characters till the next `"`
  - `(?=` Positive lookahead

    - `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
    - `(?:[^\s=]+="|>)` Match either non whitespace chars except the `=` until you match the `=` and `"` OR match `>`
  - `)` Close lookahead
- `)` Close group 2

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/haB6G) | [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/49vldD/1)

```
$text = 'advcd<img loading="lazy" class="abcd pqr" alt="chi-phi-sinh-o-benh-v"ien-dai-hoc-y-duoc-co-so-2" attr="val"><img loading="lazy" class="abcd pqr" alt="abcd-sinh-o-benh-"ien-dai-hoc-y-duoc-co-so-3">sdfs';

preg_match_all('/(alt)=(".*?"(?=\s*(?:[^\s=]+="|>)))/i', $text, $matches);

if (count($matches) > 1) {
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => alt="chi-phi-sinh-o-benh-v"ien-dai-hoc-y-duoc-co-so-2"
            [1] => alt="abcd-sinh-o-benh-"ien-dai-hoc-y-duoc-co-so-3"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => alt
            [1] => alt
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => "chi-phi-sinh-o-benh-v"ien-dai-hoc-y-duoc-co-so-2"
            [1] => "abcd-sinh-o-benh-"ien-dai-hoc-y-duoc-co-so-3"
        )

)
```

Comment: Your regex solution worked for me, Thanks a lot for your time and input

Answer (score 1):

It seems the structure is wrong and before `"` the `\` should be added. But the following regex leads to a solution.

```
(alt)=((["\']).*?[^\\]\3)(?:\s|>)
```

`\3`: matches to 3rd match group. It is used because the value should end with the same sign that started with (`"` or `'`).

`[^\\]\3`: Before the end quotation sign, `\` is escaped the closing.

`(?:\s|>)` after `"` or `'` a space or '>' is required.

https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/DmU